# Prob. 6, Exercises 8.14, in Apostol's CALCULUS Vol II: Given a scalar field differentiable at a point ...

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Here is Prob. 6, Exercises 8.14, in the book *Calculus* Vol. II by Tom M. Apostol, 2nd edition:

> Given a scalar field differentiable at a point $\mathbf{a}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, suppose that $f^\prime(\mathbf{a}; \mathbf{y})=1$ and $f^\prime(\mathbf{a}; \mathbf{z})=2$, where $\mathbf{y} = 2\mathbf{i}+3\mathbf{j}$ and $\mathbf{z} = \mathbf{i} + \mathbf{j}$. Make a sketch showing the set of all points $(x, y)$ for which $f^\prime(\mathbf{a}; x\mathbf{i}+y\mathbf{j})=6$. Also, calculate the gradient $\nabla f(\mathbf{a})$.

My Attempt:

> As $f$ is differentiable at $\mathbf{a}$, so for every $\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ the directional derivative $f^\prime(\mathbf{a}; \mathbf{b})$ exists and is given by 
>   $$ f^\prime(\mathbf{a}; \mathbf{b}) = \nabla f(\mathbf{a}) \cdot \mathbf{b}.  $$
>
> Now let $(u, v)$ be the gradient vector of $f$ at the point $\mathbf{a}$. Then from the given information we can conclude that 
>   $$ 2u + 3v = 1 \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad u+v = 2, $$
>   and upon solving these two equations simultaneously for $u$ and $v$ we get $u = 5$ and $v=-3$. Thus 
>   $$ \nabla f(\mathbf{a}) = (5, -3). $$

Am I right?

> Thus the set of all the points $(x, y)$ for which $f^\prime(\mathbf{a}; x\mathbf{i} + y\mathbf{j})=6$ is 
>   $$ \left\{ \ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ \colon \ 5x-3y=6 \ \right\}, $$
>   which is the straight line in the plane through the point (0, -2) and having the slope $5/3$.

Am I right?

Comment: Yes. it is right.